# Failed to find class JsonObject

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class

In an android project I have added as an external jar: gson-2.3.jar
But I keep getting:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/gson/JsonObject;

I tried to debug it and I see the code goes to `protected final Class<?> findLoadedClass(String className)` and the `return VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(loader, className);` return null

Then this

```
clazz = parent.loadClass(className, false);
```

throws: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonObject`

What am I  messing up here?
I see that the gson-2.3.jar is part of the external jars and I cleaned/rebuild the project

Comment: in the property of your project , select gson-2.3.jar as exported library

Comment: @Ishrat:Where is this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select gson-2.3.jar as exported library,

Right click on project then click on **Build Path** then **Configure Build Path**
select **Order and Export**, then check Export external library.